# Progressive number in a class

Tags: c++

I'll explain my problem to you.
I have a class called BankAccount which has a vector of objects of type Transaction.
The BankAccount class has a method called assignID () that assigns a unique ID to each newly added transaction to the vector.
I thought of declaring an integer within the BankAccount class called progressiveNumber that is assigned to each new transaction added to the carrier, and then increase, and so on.
My teacher after viewing it said that progressiveNumber should be "enum" instead of "int".
It's possible? if not possible, how can I do this without using "int"?

Comment: I'd recommend you asking you teacher first. From your perspective it's a very valid case for `int` and definetely not for `enum`, but you might have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: There could be enums used for other types in this class. Perhaps transaction type however I don't see a use case for a transaction ID being an enum.

Comment: Even if you have explained it quite sufficient. Can you provide your code to your question?

Comment: In C++17 (relying on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/enumerations-cpp?view=vs-2019))  one could use an enum with an explicit underlying type but without enumerators, essentially creating a new integral type without implicit conversion to the underlying type. This would be more **type-safe** and prevent errors when used as arguments to functions which expect zip codes, money amounts or other numbers. You'll have to cast every time you *do* want to use it as a number though, e.g. for incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

If progressiveNumber values are known then it is possible and valid way to do. Think about seasons, you have "Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter". Would you rather create an array/list of string to keep them or you simply create an enum called "Sesons" and you store your stuff in there ready to use easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately the progressive number can be increased unlimitedly because it is not possible to know how many transactions will be added.
It is an application for banking transactions and each time the user makes a transaction, it is added to the carrier and the progressive number is consequently increased

Comment: unfortunately I also think so.
Do you know other ways to do it?
Thanks anyway for your availability

Comment: I would make this a static class member unsigned int or int.

Comment: If that's the case it is not possible or not feasible to use enum type for this.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are possible but i would prefer using unsigned int for your case.

Try do some format with index of transaction in vector and bank account
Best way is to do some formating in bytes. In that way you can make ID of transaction in way that is actualy usable.
Something like 12 Bytes of BankAccountID and 12B that is Transaction_Index in vector of bank account. It will be faster and transaction can be tracked globaly so you dont have to browse bank accounts for every transaction. This way finding the transaction will be O(1).

Use the Byte encoding and then just convert it to uint256 or from uint256.

I hoped this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your answers and availability, I regret not having attached the code to the question but I have only today registered for this platform and I still have to get used to it.

however I think I put the progressiveNumber attribute as static int and declare a get method and an assignID () method